# Array of Map Annotation

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.3

How do i create an array of annotations in mapview for Xcode? I hav tried 
NSMutableArray *ann = [NSMutableArray alloc]init];

the annotation

```
CLLocationcoordinate2D thecoordinate;
thecoordinate.latitude =92.3;
thecoordinate.longitude = 12.78;
MyAnnotationClass *ann = [MyAnnotationClass alloc];
region.coordinate = thecoordinate;
[mapview addannotation: ann];
```

I have 57 of these how do i put them in an array.

Answer (score 2):

send the message addObject to NSMutableArray.

```
NSMutableArray* annotationArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[annotationArray addObject:ann]; //ann is an instance of MyAnnotationClass. Call this method for every MyAnnotationClass object you have.
```

Another option is to init the array with objects:

```
NSMutableArray* annotationArray =[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: arr1, arr2, arr3, arr4, nil]; //arr1,arr2... are your MyAnnotationClass objects.
```

You can then add the anotations to the mapview all at once:

```
[mapview addAnnotations:annotationArray];
```

Comment: Can i implement it in a table view for the titles to populate a table ?

Comment: @JamesFrempong you can implement this wherever you want. Actually tableViews are usually populated from NSArray or NSMutableArray.